# Mandocs Error while building Linux kernel 3.4.6 with Xenomai on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kernel

I am trying to build the Linux kernel version 3.4.6 with Xenomai 2.6.2.1. I am also trying to build it as a debian package using
`make-kpkg --append-to-version -xenomai --initrd buildpackage`.
I am using GCC 4.9.3

The modules all are built correctly barring a few warnings regarding exceeding frame size and uninitialised variables. But in the stage 2 of building modules, while building the documentation, the problems start with warnings of the following type

`Warn: meta author : no refentry/info/author                        usb_hcd_pci_probe`

This then leads to the following type of warnings

`Warn: AUTHOR sect.: no personblurb|contrib for Jeff Garzik`

This then leads to the following error

```
Note: Writing sil_dev_config.9
Makefile:1326: recipe for target 'mandocs' failed
make[3]: *** [mandocs] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-3.4.6'
debian/ruleset/targets/doc.mk:34: recipe for target 
'debian/stamp/install/linux-doc-3.4.6-xenomai' failed
make[2]: *** [debian/stamp/install/linux-doc-3.4.6-xenomai] Error 2
```

The build step finally dumps the [following output (pastebin link)](https://pastebin.com/AuUAb6RC) and quits.
I am not used to Linux kernel builds and this around my sixth unsuccessful attempt at this. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am following the steps in [this link](https://www.blaess.fr/christophe/2011/12/28/xenomai-2-6-0-sur-ubuntu-11-10/) but just modified for my Linux kernel version (the version in the article caused issues while building modules).

Comment: Cross posted https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432834/mandocs-error-while-building-linux-kernel-3-4-6-with-xenomai

Comment: Btw, it looks to me similar error to missing dependency (missing command) which used to build mandocs. How did you prepare your dev tools or check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile if you didn't make it already.